# Bootstrap popover width for popover-inner

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like the have a Bootstrap Popover be wider.  I read that this should work:

```
.popover-inner a {
   width: 600px;
}
```

But, the browser console still shows auto with the above code.  Hard to describe.  Here is a snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Based off of what I have in my bootstrap.css file, the default is a max-width property.

I use this

```
.popover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1010;
  display: none;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  white-space: normal;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     -moz-border-radius: 6px;
          border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
     -moz-background-clip: padding;
          background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

and it works exactly how you intended it to.

My bootstrap.css files does not contain a popover-inner a css selector at all though

Comment: What if you just want the popover to be wider in one certain page? Or... how do I change the width dynamically? Did anyone have to face this?

Comment: Why does bootstrap do this? I have wondered this for a long time.

Comment: @trysis: quote from https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/popover -- "The maximum width of the popover is hard coded by Bootstrap v4 CSS to 276px. Tall popovers on small screens can be harder to deal with on mobile devices (such as smart-phones)."

Answer (score 26):

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2332) on bootstrap to make this easier, but you can [modify it using this technique](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/2332#issuecomment-10132668) of setting the `template` option for the popover:

```
$('#yourPopover').popover({
  template: '<div class="popover special-class"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>'
})
```

Then you can set your popover `special-class` css however you like (widths and more!)

Answer (score 24):

```
.popover {
  max-width: 600px;
  width: auto;
}
```

change max-width to your desired value, You can also set `min-width`, if you wish

Answer (score 6):

If you want to control the minimum width of your popover window, just add an extra line in the css (or extra css) like this:

```
.popover
{
    min-width: 200px ! important;
}
```

(replace 200px with the desired value)

Answer (score 3):

1)Easy way :(warning:this will affect all popovers):

Just override the bootstrap .popover styles as below

```
.popover{
    max-width: 600px; 
}
```

2)Recommended  way:

```
$("#a-div-id-001").popover({
    //set a custom container
    // which can minimize the displacement of popover
    //when window resizing
    container: $("#Div"),
    html : true,
    content: function() {
        return "<span>Hello there!</span>";
    },
    viewport: {
        selector: 'body',
        padding: 10
    },
    title:"Apps",
    template:'<div class="popover my-custom-class" role="tooltip">'
        +'<div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3>'
        +'<div class="popover-content"></div>'
        +'</div>'
});
```

First add a custom class to the popover template like above my-custom-class. Note that popover will be rendered in using the default template unless you had specified a custom template.

Then override bootstrap's .popover styles like below :

```
div.popover.my-custom-class{
    max-width: 600px;
}
```

This styles let you to have a dynamic width up to 600px. If you need to set a minimum width to the popover, just set the width option directly. see example below,

```
div.popover.my-custom-class{
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

When you increase the width, you may need to adjust the space (offset) between the popover box and the left/right page border. See the viewport property, as it sets the bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Disable `max-width` in `.popover`:

```
.popover {
    max-width: none;
}
```

And then you can play with the size of the content more freely.

Answer (score 2):

Some answer herein recommend just making the `popover` class a certain width. This is no good, because it affects all popovers. Use something like this instead, something more targeted:

```
.container-div .popover {
    /* add styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample initialization that I use.

```
    $(".property-price")
    .popover({ 
            trigger: "hover", 
            placement: 'bottom',
            toggle : "popover",
            content : "The from price is calculated ba....the dates selected.",
            title: "How is the from price calculated?",
            container: 'body',
            template: '<div class="popover popover-medium"><div class="arrow"></div><div class="popover-inner"><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"><p></p></div></div></div>',
        });
```

As you can see, it uses a custom template. The template uses a custom popover-medium class.

I then have a CSS selector

```
.popover-medium {
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

You could also just set a style on the template class if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
width:auto;
...
```

was the perfect solution in my case. I had multiple popovers on the same page and one of them has a long URL. All of them looks nice now. Thank you JFK!

Answer (score 0):

Add your popover content as HTML with your own class and then in CSS file add:

```
.popover .own-class { width: ... }
```

".own-class" element width will determine popover width.