# Bootstrap - Aligning select and submit within form within popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a select, an input, and a button to align inside an inline form that's within a popover, but as of yet I've had no success. I've followed the docs and tried to experiment with different widths for the select, but to no avail

**Edit:** Updated to reflect Eric B's suggestion

Code:

```
<li><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" type="button" href="#" id="login" >Login</a></li>
            <div id="popover-head" class="hide">Login</div>
            <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>NA</option>
                            <option>RU</option>
                            <option>EU</option>
                            <option>SEA</option>
                        </select> 
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="5">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go To Login &raquo;</button>                                  
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Output:
[Example http://puu.sh/4XWmi.png](http://puu.sh/4XWmi.png)

Comment: What kind of alignment you are talking about?

Comment: My guess is your popover isnt wide enough so the arent all appearing on the same line. try adding a static with to the form-group div and see if that accomplishes what you want.

Comment: i believe popover has a max width at 300px - see some workarounds here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776487/bootstrap-popover-width-for-popover-inner

Comment: Can you do a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're seeing 2 problems..

First, in Bootstrap 3, the form inputs are no longer set to a specific width, so you need to set a width for the inputs to prevent stacking. This can be done by overriding `.form-control` or set the width by using a `style=` attribute on your inputs.

Secondly, the Bootstrap `.popover` has a `max-width` of 276px, so you need to increase the width accordingly...

```
.form-control {width:120px;}
.popover {max-width:400px;}
```

Working demo: http://bootply.com/89823

Answer (score 0):

Try NOT wrapping each one in their own `<div>` tag. But wrapping all 3 in one  `<div>` tag.

```
   <li><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" type="button" href="#" id="login" >Login</a></li>
            <div id="popover-head" class="hide">Login</div>
            <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
                <form class="form-inline" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control" width="20%">
                            <option>NA</option>
                            <option>RU</option>
                            <option>EU</option>
                            <option>SEA</option>
                        </select>                                   
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" maxlength="5" width="20%">
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" width="20%">Go &raquo;</button>
                     </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

Comment: Updated Original post

Comment: Did that work, I'm not sure what just happened? Now your code looks just like what I suggested...

Comment: No, the 3 elements should be in a line. Not stacked

Comment: Have you tried adding a width property to each element and either setting it to a percentage or a pixel width of something small? Look at what I just did to the code I posted. That might  help you control the size of each item.

Comment: Your popover is to narrow. so you either need to ad a width property to it or what I just suggested above.