# Changing the width of twitter bootstrap popover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to change the width of twitter bootstrap popover using bootstrap 3:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
```

```javascript
$('#popover').popover(options)
```

At the moment the content in the popover spreads over two lines. I want the popover content to stay on one line. Is this possible?

I am using C#, html and css.

Comment: You can change the max-width css property for .popover. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776487/bootstrap-popover-width-for-popover-inner

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can change the popover's dimensions with CSS:

```
.popover{
    width:200px;
    height:250px;    
}
```

But that CSS will change ALL popovers. What you need to do is put the button in a container element and use CSS like this:

```
#containerElem .popover {
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  max-width:none; // Required for popovers wider than 276px (Bootstrap's max-width for popovers)
}
```

You also need to change `data-container="#containerElem"` to match your container.

NOTE: If your popover is going to have a width greater than 276px, you need to override the `max-width` property as well. So add `max-width: none` to the `.popover {}` class.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4FMmA/

Comment: Thankyou this is a great answer. The wrap is great, but if I set the width on the container to '10000px' 'Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue' is still on one line while 'laoreet rutrum faucibus' is on the second line

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/4FMmA/1/ I actually don't see a difference with the 10000px width on the container element.

Comment: Now each word is on a separate line for each fiddle? By setting the width of the wrap I was hoping everything would be on one line.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, so you want to make the popover long enough to not wrap the text. Let me check it out and see what's happening.

Comment: Bootstrap sets a `max-width` property in their CSS, so I just had to override this. This fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/w5NdV/

Comment: Good answer, worked for me. Though I found:  "max-width: 600px; width: auto;" also worked.

Comment: Worked for me though did need to include !important to override the values set in bootstrap.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to controle the width in javascript:

**HTML (example from Bootstrap)**

```
<button id="exampleButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top</button>
```

**Javascript:**

We set the max-width when `show.bs.popover` event is triggered:

```
var p = $("#exampleButton").popover();
p.on("show.bs.popover", function(e){
    p.data("bs.popover").tip().css({"max-width": "500px"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ctoesca/u3kSk

---

- You can also add a `data-max-width` attribute on the button element and get the value in the trigger function:

```
p.on("show.bs.popover", function(e){
    var w = $(this).attr("data-max-width");
    p.data("bs.popover").tip().css({"max-width": w});
});
```

Answer (score 12):

```
.popover{
    max-width: 100%;
    width: <width>;
}
```

The 'max-width' sets max-width of popover to the width of the page.
You can then set the width as you like

Comment: I tried 20 different versions and this one only works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust the width of the popover, but the best thing to do is to define the width of the content before Bootstrap sees is.  For instance, I had a table, I defined it's width, then bootstrap built a popover to suit it.  (Sometimes Bootstrap has trouble determining the width, and you need to step in and hold its hand)

Answer (score 2):

I might have an easier solution:

Add the following **css class**:

`.app-popover-fw { width: 276px; }`

Use the following **template** for your popover

```
var newPopoverTemplate = '<div class="popover app-popover-fw" role="popover">' +
                             '<div class="arrow"></div>'+ 
                             '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>'+
                             '<div class="popover-content"></div>'+
                          '</div>';

$('#example').popover({template: newPopoverTemplate });`
```

**Working fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/b5Ly2ynd/

**NB**: As others said, there is a "max-width" property on bs popovers. You need to alter this one if you want your popover larger than 276px.

Answer (score 2):

Use this code . It will work fine:

```
  .popover{
       background-color:#b94a48;
       border:none;
       border-radius:unset;
       min-width:100px;
       width:100%;
       max-width:400px;
       overflow-wrap:break-word;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code:

```
.popover {
      width: 600px;
      max-width: 600px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-family: Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,"Courier New",monospace;
      word-break: break-all;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      white-space: pre;
      width: 600px;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use custom template like (added only additional class: popover-lg):

```
<div class="popover popover-lg" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-title"></h3><div class="popover-content"></div></div>
```

Then in css:

```
.popover-lg {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Invocation:

```
$(".your-element")..popover({
        trigger: "hover",
        template: templateString,
        container: "body",
        content: '...',
    });
```

This way it is clean and doesn't interfere original bootstrap behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in two ways, one is by reducing the font-size for class 'popover' and the other is by reducing the padding in class 'popover-content'. Here is how I achieved it,

```
.popover {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.popover-content {
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to increase the width of your popover.

```
.popover{
    max-width: 100%; /* Max Width of the popover (depending on the container!) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best method I have found to affect the popover properties without directly overriding them in a CSS override class, is to use the container attribute when instantiating the popover, then using a complex selector to override the properties, thereby keeping the original properties for any other popovers you may want in some other area of your site.

Simply overriding max-width in the .popover will work of course, but then you have to live with that override for everything, essentially defeating the purpose.

What I do is set the container of my popover to the container of the triggering element, then creating a complex CSS class like .container > .popover that sets the max-width the popover only for that instance.